# Problems mounting an encrypted volume on a different computer

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, mount, encryption, usb-drive

I have a set of external hard drives that I use for backups of my photos and images. They were formatted as EXT4 and setup with encryption from a laptop running Ubuntu 10.04 - and I've had no problems with mounting and running rsync on my image folders to backup new files to the disks.

I recently acquired a netbook for travel purposes, and am trying to get the drives to also work on this so I can make backups while on holiday. The netbook is running Ubuntu 11.04.

When I first plugged in one of the drives, I was asked for the password, which I entered, and the disk activity light started blinking, but no file window opened as I expected. However, I did not get any error messages, either.

When I opened a file window, I could see the volume listed as "Backup Alpha" (the disk's name) but when I tried to open it, I received the error:

```
Unable to mount "Backup Alpha"

/dev/dm-0 is mounted
```

When I try to unmount the drive, by right-clicking and selecting the "safely remove drive" option, I get the message:

```
Unable to stop 500 GB Hard Drive

One or more block devices are holding /dev/sdb
```

One problem I did have when initially trying to access the drive was that `cryptsetup` had not yet been installed on the computer, and so the first time I tried to enter a password and access the drive failed.

I found a way to disable automount, but now I'm having problems manually mounting the drive:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/backup -o uid=1000,gid=1000,utf8,dmask=027,fmask=137
mount: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'
```

I found some help at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=868681 and tried:

```
$ mkdir /media/backup
$ modprobe dm-crypt
$ cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb backup
$ vgchange -ay
$ mount /dev/("volume group name") /media/backup
```

The problem is that `vgchange` doesn't output any volume groups, and I still can't mount `/dev/sdb`

Comment: You mentioned your use of cryptsetup: When mounting volumes that are encrypted, you must first run `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb backup`and then run `sudo mount /dev/mapper/backup /media/backup`. If you don't have a /media/backup folder, then you must create one by running `sudo mkdir /media/backup` _before_ mounting /dev/mapper/backup.

Answer (score 2):

It seems trouble around ***automount*** feature.
Try uncheck this option and ***mount/unmount*** drive after ***logout/login***.

Just due to *mount/unmount* of encrypted drives requires a bit more time for this operation - with *automount* option it can bring such little confuse. Logically.

But in practice it can be also multiuser exploring of your drives, by edge case.

Refer to this tutorial about two types of partition mounting:

- [AutomaticallyMountPartitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions)

I recommend you read part called "***Unmounting a partition to prevent unwanted access***".

---

***Post Updates***

> *WebUpd8.org* post around ***mount/unmount*** :
> [How to remove mounted drives from the Ubuntu Unity launcher](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-remove-mounted-drives-from.html)

---

> ***LUKS encryption related***
>
> Official LUKS project: http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup
> FAQ: [LUKS Frequently Asked Questions](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)
>
> Obviously it seems can be Natty Narwhal specific bug.
> Need to say what launchpad fix especially for natty won't be released.
> *However, bug fixes for other distributions is exist.*
>
> Links for you:
> [LUKS: General Questions](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup): *1.3 System Specific warnings*
> [LUKS: Common Problems](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#3._Common_Problems)
> [LUKS: Issues with Specific Versions of cryptsetup](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#8._Issues_with_Specific_Versions_of_cryptsetup)
>
> As edge solution you can *add new* **and** *then remove old* LUKS encryption key:
>
> ```
>    $ sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdb [key|keyfile]  
>    $ sudo cryptsetup luksRemoveKey /dev/sdb [key|keyfile]
> ```
>
> From [LUKS: Common Problems: 3.4 Unlocking a LUKS device takes very long. Why?](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#3._Common_Problems)
>
> > > The iteration time for a key-slot (see Section 5 for an explanation what iteration does) is calculated when setting a ***passphrase***. By default it is 1 second on the machine where the ***passphrase*** is set. *****If you set a passphrase on a fast machine and then unlock it on a slow machine, the unlocking time can be much longer.***** Also take into account that up to 8 key-slots have to be tried in order to find the right one.
> > >
> > > If this is problem, you can add another key-slot using the slow machine with the same
> > > ***passphrase*** and then remove the old key-slot. The new key-slot will have an iteration count adjusted to 1 second on the slow machine. Use `luksKeyAdd` and then `luksKillSlot` or `luksRemoveKey`.
> > >
> > > However, this operation will not change volume key iteration count (MK iterations in output of "`cryptsetup luksDump`"). In order to change that, you will have to backup the data in the *LUKS container* (i.e. your encrypted data), `luksFormat` on the slow machine and restore the data. Note that in the *original LUKS specification* this value was fixed to 10, but it is now derived from the *PBKDF2* benchmark as well and set to iterations in 0.125 sec or 1000, whichever is larger. Also note that MK iterations are not very security relevant. *But as each key-slot already takes 1 second, spending the additional 0.125 seconds really does not matter*.

---

> ***Another LUKS tutorial:***
> [HOWTO: Automatically Unlock LUKS Encrypted Drives With A Keyfile](http://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile)

Comment: where is this option?

Comment: turned it up at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Configuring_Automounting - was confused because the documentation refers to gnome, not unity

Comment: hm ... No. This help refers to Ubuntu Help, not GNOME.
I have other helpful link for your Oneiric:
http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-remove-mounted-drives-from.html

Comment: sorry, Natty Narwhal :) Post updated.
Hope it help you to figure out your the best solution.

Comment: i meant my link... but I have been able to disable automounting - my problem now is the unknown format...

Comment: "mount -o" options set depends on specific filesystem.
"vgchange" works for active volume only. 
http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: I mean ... you are sure that this option set suitable for EXT4 ?

Comment: try "cryptsetup status <mapping name>"

From http://linux.die.net/man/8/cryptsetup:
" LUKS checks for a valid password or key when an encrypted partition is unlocked. Thus the luksOpen action fails with invalid password or key, contrary to the plain dm-crypt create action. Please also be sure that you are using the same keyboard and language setting as during device format."